# Calculus resources with a probability and statistics slant?

Tags: references

I'm taking a statistical learning class, and I need to brush up on my calculus. I already took calculus and probability several years ago, but I have a bad memory.

Are there any good books or general resources that give a review of calculus with a probability and statistics slant? I noticed that most calculus books give examples in the context of physics. In general, I'm looking for a book like [Calculus Refresher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486203700), except more targeted towards probability and statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andre Khuri's *Advanced Calculus with Applications in Statistics* comes to mind first ([Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471391042)).

I browsed a few chapters of it some time ago and from what I remember it contains what you're looking for.